# convert a pandas statement to a numpy statement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following pandas statement:

```
df['temp'] = np.where((c - e).abs() < threshold, 0, np.where(c > e, +1, -1))
s = df['temp'].where(df['temp'].groupby(df['temp'].ne(df['temp'].shift()).cumsum()).transform('size').ge(min_length), 0)
```

but I don't want to use a temp column, so I can simply rewrite the first line:

```
temp = np.where((c - e).abs() < threshold, 0, np.where(c > e, +1, -1))
```

and I have a numpy array; but now the question is how to rewrite the second line for numpy?

Comment: The second line uses `groupby`, which does not exist in `numpy`.  What is `temp` after the 1st line?  Is it `ndarray` or `pandas.Series`?

Comment: What are `c`,`e`,and `threshold` ?

Comment: I'm trying to run the code this belongs to in multiple threads with the multiprocessing module, so I'm looking for a way to not write in the dataframe

Comment: @MattR, they're just local variables (ints)

Comment: Right. but are they series, ints, floats, strings, etc.

Comment: they're all ints

Answer (score 0):

That code chink is looking for sequences of values that aren't changing that are longer than `min_length` and setting them to `0`.

You can do the same with:

```
_, i, c = np.unique(np.cumsum(temp[1:] != temp[:-1]), return_counts = True, return_inverse = True)
temp[1:][(c >= min_length)[i]] = 0
```

Comment: this is not producing the same result at all as the original code